# (C++) Const-Reference modified?

Tags: c++, constants

I'm trying to write a string class which can perform most of std::string's actions. Actually, I'm stuck with my "insert" function.

```
template <typename T>
class string_base {
public:
... 
/// INSERT FUNCTION 
// len = current string length of *this
// cap = current capacity of this->raw_data
// raw_data = array which holds all characters
// DEF_ALLOC = 8192
// T = type of element (char, wchar_t, char16_t, char32_t), in my case: char
// str.data() returns the char array of the "str" parameter 
// str.length() returns "len" variable of "str"

string_base<T> &insert(const string_base<T> &str, unsigned pos) {
    if (pos > len || !str.length()) return *this;
    unsigned o = len;
    if (cap <= (len += str.length())) {
        cap += (str.length() + DEF_ALLOC);
        raw_data = (T *)realloc(raw_data, (cap * sizeof(T)));
    }
    if (pos) {
        for (unsigned i = o; i >= pos; i--)
            raw_data[i + str.length()] = raw_data[i];
    } else {
        for (unsigned i = o; i > 0; i--)
            raw_data[i + str.length()] = raw_data[i];
        raw_data[str.length()] = raw_data[0];
    }
    for (unsigned i = pos; i < (pos + str.length()); i++)
        raw_data[i] = str.data()[i - pos];
    raw_data[len] = 0x00;
    return *this;
}
private:
T *raw_data;
unsigned len, cap;
};

typedef string_base<char> string;
typedef string_base<wchar_t> wstring;
typedef string_base<char16_t> string16;
typedef string_base<char32_t> string32;
```

As we can see the function takes a parameter as a const-reference (Which can't be changed by the function as far as I know)
I call the function like that:

```
string_base<char> a("Roses are red"); // assign "Roses are red" to a's char array
string_base<char> b("not "); 
//a.insert(b, 10); -> this works correctly  
a.insert(a, 10); // when I pass "a", it does shit
```

I insert "a" into "a" at position 10
"a" (it's char array) should now have a value of "Roses are Roses are redred".
Instead of that, it has a value of "Roses are Roses are Roses ".
I might need to add that the function itself works fine, I just have a problem with this const reference...

I think the "insert" function modifies the passed parameter as well, but it shouldn't.
Is there any way how I can prevent or fix that?

Thanks in advance! I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: hint: `this == &str` is true when you call `a.insert(a, 10)`

Comment: Thanks, Frank! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify an object through a reference-to-const.  That doesn't mean you can't modify that object through other references though.

As a simple example, the following is perfectly valid and will print "100":

```
int main() {
    int i = 42;
    int& ri = i;
    const int& cri = i;

    ri = 100;
    std::cout << cri;
}
```

The changes made through `ri` are reflected through `cri` since both refer to the same object.

Your call to `a.insert(a, 10)` is the same situation.  `str` and `this` both refer to the same object.  Any changes you make to the current object will also be reflected through `str`.  That means when you shift characters around in the reallocated buffer you're modifying the data that will be copied.